# Using DevExpress Controls in existing WPF projects

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I am working on a WPF solution (contains 14 projects) in VS-2017

I would like to use DevExpress for the implementation of some controls like (Ribbon, Status Bar ...etc)

After installation I can't find the DevExpress controls in the toolbox.

I added a reference `(DevExpress.Xpf.Ribbon.v18.2)` to one of my projects and 
 I still can't use the DX Ribbon control or find it in the toolbox

being beginner in this, I would like to know how to configure this correctly ?

Comment: Essentially this https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/integration/installation-adding-to-vs-toolbox but you point to the devexpress dll in their sdk install location. The real solution, however, is to tackle that learning curve and start writing your UI in xaml rather than using drag/drop. You'll want to do that anyhow after you start experiencing how that editor fills your UI with completely useless and unwanted crap (margins... margins everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this DevExpress KB - [How to resolve issues with Toolbox items](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18574/how-to-resolve-issues-with-toolbox-items)

> If you installed Visual Studio after the installation of our products,
>   re-run our installer in Repair mode to register our toolbox items for
>   that Visual Studio.